# Does anybody know how to uninstall a malicious chrome addon called websecurity?

Tags: google-chrome, malware

Does anybody know how to uninstall a chrome addon called websecurity? One day it randomly appeared in chrome. It says it was installed by an enterprise policy. I have tried searching for its extension number in regedit, but it wouldn't respond. I deleted it's folder in C:\Users\RRH30_000\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions, but it's still here. I would absolutely love it if someone helped me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you nuke the entire chrome profile what happens?

Comment: Do you mean delete?

Comment: That's what it means to nuke a file or folder.....

Comment: Look for "Web Security App" (or similar) in the programs and features list (control panel) uninstall it then install and run adwcleaner to clean up residuals...http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/

Comment: Already tried. It's not in control panel.

Comment: Do you mean the folder in appdata?

Comment: I would uninstall chrome and download a clean/new version.

Comment: "It says it was installed by an enterprise policy" Perhaps your IT department installed it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Chrome and kill all running Chrome processes.
2. Start Chrome with the `--disable-extensions --disable-plugins` command-line options to disable all extensions and plugins.
3. Go to Settings/Extensions, and trash what you want trashed.

If this doesn't help, it is a different issue.

You can also (after step 1) use REGEDIT to delete the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome` and anything below it.